# How to plot a set of coordinates with complex and real entries?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot the spectrum of an operator where the x-axis should display the imaginary parts , while the y-axis should show the resolvent norm.

The points are :

```
spectrum = {{-I, -0.00007101571085985984`}, {I, \
-0.00007101571085985984`}, {2 I, -0.00007101157856391203`}, {-2 I, \
-0.00007101157856391203`}, {3 I, -0.00007100469269888534`}, {-3 I, \
-0.00007100469269888534`}, {4 I, -0.00007099505520609025`}, {-4 I, \
-0.00007099505520609025`}, {5 I, -0.00007098266880132528`}, {-5 I, \
-0.00007098266880132528`}, {6 I, -0.00007096753697284396`}, {-6 I, \
-0.00007096753697284396`}, {7 I, -0.00007094966397874663`}, {-7 I, \
-0.00007094966397874663`}, {8 I, -0.00007092905484379976`}, {-8 I, \
-0.00007092905484379976`}, {9 I, -0.00007090571535568844`}, {-9 I, \
-0.00007090571535568844`}, {10 I, -0.00007087965206070632`}, {-10 I, \
-0.00007087965206070632`}, {11 I, -0.0000708508722588905`}, {-11 I, \
-0.0000708508722588905`}, {12 I, -0.00007081938399860719`}, {-12 I, \
-0.00007081938399860719`}, {13 I, -0.00007078519607059655`}, {-13 I, \
-0.00007078519607059655`}, {14 I, -0.00007074831800148508`}, {-14 I, \
-0.00007074831800148508`}}
```

However, when I try with ListPlot:

```
ListPlot[spectrum]
```

It is blank. I assume this is because the x-entries are complex. Is there a "complex list plot"?

So I tried:

```
ComplexListPlot[spectrum]
```

But also this is blank.

Any suggestion what is best here?

Thanks

Comment: It is tried already. Didn't work for some reason. See the end of the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to the following perhaps:

```
xvals = Im@First@# & /@ spectrum
yvals = Abs@*Last /@ spectrum
ListLinePlot[SortBy[First][Transpose[{xvals, yvals}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It seems it was not easy to solve this problem. Is it possible to highlight the points on the plot?

Comment: Use `Mesh -> All` and change `MeshStyle` as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for that!